# swift: Combine non-overlapping images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Every similar question I've seen relates to merging `UIImage`s by placing one image on top of the other. Instead, I'd like the images to be **adjacent** to each other. I have a rectangle image and a triangle image and I'd like to make a new image with the square on top and the triangle beneath it.

```
--------
|      |        
|      |
--------
```

PLUS

```
--
\/
```

EQUALS

```
--------
|      |        
|      |
---  ---
   \/
```

*I don't want*:

```
--------
|  --  |        
|  \/  |
--------
```

Answer (score 0):

So create an image context the size of the combined images, and render the images into it with drawInRect.